# TypeScript Module Augmentation - Reference to Full Instance as 'this' instead of subproperty

Tags: typescript, class, module, this

I want to extend a class from some library by adding my own utility functions under the `util` property to it. (Written in TypeScript, using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation))

When I call my methods like so: `someClassInstance.util.doSomething()`, they do not receive the full `someClassInstance`, but only the property `util`, which we already know.

However, these functions need the values from each `SomeClass` instance when called.

Is there a way to receive the upper scope (`someClassInstance`) instead of `someClassInstance.util` as `this`?

I know it would be easier to implement just passing in the instance as a parameter to the function, but that would make consuming my methods not as nice, as you'd effectively be repeating yourself (`someClassInstance.util.doSomething(someClassInstance)` contains the instance twice)

```
import * as exported from './[SAME_FILE]';
import { SomeClass } from 'SomeLibrary';

declare module 'SomeLibrary' {
    interface SomeClass {
        util: typeof exported;
    }
}

SomeClass.prototype.util = exported;

// Does not work, expects an instance of SomeClass, 
// but can only receive SomeClass.util
export async function doSomething(this: SomeClass) {
    // do something with `this` (= someClassInstance)
}
```

*Example Implementation*

Comment: I'd love to see a more fleshed out [mcve] here, especially one that could be run in a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). Since TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript, I wonder how you would write this in JavaScript?  It seems unlikely that `util` can really be on the prototype of `SomeClass` because it needs to know about the instance of `SomeClass` on which you access `util`.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgrlBW) meet your needs?  It's quite awful; the only way I can think of to get behavior like this is to modify the constructor you import.  If it works for you, I might write it up as an answer with huge caveats.  Otherwise, I'm inclined to think what you're asking for is either impossible or strongly inadvisable.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this issue isn't typescript-specific, it appears to be a limitation of extending a prototype. I could change the snippet to make it more general/reproducible, but I fear that what I'm trying to do is too much effort in the first place.

Comment: @jcalz Technically that does solve the problem, although its pretty ugly and I've given up and just passed in the instance as a parameter instead... Thank you for putting your time into this though, could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as solution?